# Square array from linear array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vector

I would like to get a square matrix `B` from a linear vector `A` such that `B = A * transpose(A)`. `A` is a numpy array and `np.shape(A)` returns `(10,)`. I would like `B` to be a `(10,10)` array. I tried `B = np.matmut(A, A[np.newaxis])` but I get an error :

> ```
> shapes (10,) and (1,10) not aligned: 10 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
> ```

Comment: What I want is the equivalent of "B=A*ctranspose(A)" in matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this using `outer`:

```
import numpy as np
vector = np.arange(10)
np.outer(vector, vector)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is a little ugly, but it does what you need.

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],)
matrix = np.dot(vector[:,None],vector[None,:])
print(matrix)
```

You can also do the following:

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],)
matrix = vector*vector[:,None]
print(matrix)
```

The issue comes from the fact that transposing a one dimensional array does not have the effect you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

Variation on outer product:

```
a = A.reshape(-1, 1) # make sure it's a column vector
B = a @ a.T
```